# StringBuffer not outputting what I expected

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I am trying to switch a `$` within a string with the character to its right. I am not allowed to use a `char[]`, so I decided to use `StringBuffer`. However, when I try to run the code with something like `H$E` it outputs `HE$H$E` I have no idea where the extra characters are coming from, and I am seeking an explanation.

```
package schrumpf.clayton.csc110.drills1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MoneyToTheRight {

static BufferedReader in;


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String input = in.readLine();
    int dollarIndex = input.indexOf("$");
    StringBuffer buffer =  new StringBuffer(input);
    char afterDollarChar = buffer.append(input).charAt((dollarIndex + 1));
    buffer.setCharAt(dollarIndex, afterDollarChar);
    buffer.setCharAt((dollarIndex + 1),'$');
    String result = buffer.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: So if you inputted "H$E" you would want the output to be "HE$"?

Comment: Thanks for providing a minimal example - but is there any reason you need to use standard input for it at all? Could you just set `String input = "H$E";` to demonstrate it?

Comment: Hint: you're calling `buffer.append(input)`, even though you've already created the `StringBuffer` with `input`. That's why the content of `input` occurs twice.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Comment: @PeterLawrey : Isn't StringBuffer Thread-safe? So wouldn't it be better than StringBuilder?

Comment: @NicholasK: It's very rare to use `StringBuffer` in a way that *uses* its thread safety. (And this code certainly doesn't.) Even when you *do* want thread safety, it's often not on a "per call synchronization" basis.

Comment: @NicholasK Using StringBuffer in a thread-safe manner is harder than it first appears, making it error-prone at best.  SimpleDateFormat isn't thread safe even though it was written by the JDK developers and used StringBuffer.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the input twice.

```
StringBuffer buffer =  new StringBuffer(input);
buffer.append(input)
```

I suggest adding it once. I also suggest using StringBuilder which replaced StringBuffer more than ten years ago.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

StringBuilder buffer =  new StringBuilder(in.nextLine());
int dollarIndex = buffer.indexOf("$");
buffer.setCharAt(dollarIndex, buffer.charAt(dollarIndex + 1));
buffer.setCharAt(dollarIndex + 1, '$');
System.out.println(buffer);
```

or as a one-liner

```
System.out.println(in.nextLine().replaceFirst("\\$(.)", "$1\\$"));
```